# Скачать бинарный файл по произвольному URL

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы при открытии страницы в браузере в текстовое поле можно было ввести URL файла, после чего JavaScript его скачал, обработал и отобразил. Я пробовал делать через XmlHttpRequest так:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, false);
request.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
request.send();

var data;
if(request.status === 200)
{
    return stringToByteBufferData(request.response);
}
```

Но оно работает только, если страница находится на том же домене, что и файл. А возможно ли сделать, чтобы он качал файл по любой прямой ссылке?

P.S. Запрос синхронный, потому что мне так удобнее, а задержка незначительна - обработка файла занимает времени на порядок больше, чем его скачивание.

Comment: только если есть доступ к серверу и возможность установить [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: А без доступа никак? Я же ведь могу просто взять и скачать файл руками, почему javascript'у для этого нужно что-то ещё? Я погуглил, пишут, что так безопасней, но я так и не понял, чем может быть это опасно и почему бы не дать автору скрипта решать самому? Другое дело, если там авторизация с помощью cookie, но мне надо просто тупо получить содержимое файла по прямой ссылке. Ну или допустим, что к одному серверу есть доступ. Что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было хотя бы с него снаружи файлы качать скриптом? Куда прописывать этот Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: ограничение `XMLHttpRequest`, куда прописать - в ответ сервера. конкретнее зависит от сервера

Comment: Куда-то в конфиг apache или nginx?